# Convert Date String

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Date String as "25 Nov 2014 10:30" and i want to convert it in as "Tue Nov 25 10:30:00 IST 2014"

```
SimpleDateFormat pendingmesstime2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");         
Date pendingmessd2;
StringBuffer pendingmesstime="25 Nov 2014 14:41";
pendingmessd2=pendingmesstime2.parse(pendingmesstim);
```

It is giving ParseException.Unparsable Date "25 Nov 2014 14:41"

Logcat is:

```
11-25 14:54:25.919: D/pendingmesstime is(21177): 25 Nov 2014 14:41
11-25 14:54:25.919: W/System.err(21177): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "   25 Nov 2014 14:41" (at offset 2)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at          java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at com.example.gate_keeper.PendingMessageFragment$1.onItemClick(PendingMessageFragment.java:184)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1394)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3024)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3830)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
11-25 14:54:25.939: W/System.err(21177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The answer is in the question. Look at the string you're trying to parse in the stack trace. Don't you see the leading white spaces? Don't you see that it doesn't match at all with the pattern you're using? There are slashes in the pattern. And there is none in the string to parse.

Comment: Why are you putting slashes in the input format when there is none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
SimpleDateFormat pendingmesstime2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
```

The date format string has to be in the same format as the string you're trying to parse. You've specified something of the form `25/11/2014 14:41`, rather than `25 Nov 2014 14:41`.

There's also something weird going on with the conversion from `StringBuffer` to `String`: you're ending up with a few extra spaces at the beginning for some reason. I can only assume this is a result of something you haven't shown us. (It looks as though you haven't copied and pasted exactly from your source, because there's at least a typo with the `pendingmesstime` variable name in the last line.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify both the input and output date format. Try this code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateConverter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DateConverter converter = new DateConverter();
    String outputDate = converter.convertDate("25 Nov 2014 14:41");
    System.out.println(outputDate);
  }

  DateConverter() {}

  public String convertDate(String inputDate)
  {
    try
    {
      Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm").parse(inputDate);
      return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date);
    }
    catch(ParseException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "Could not parse date";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Date variable from a string. Your format is for **recognizing** a string as Date. You're entering the output format as input format. Change it and it'll work fine. Your format should be:

```
 25 Nov 2014 14:41
 dd MMM yyyy HH:mm
```